# Composer on live server

Tags: composer-php

I have moved my composer based project to a live server.  Accountrix is complaining about my `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files. Do I need these files on the live server or is it ok to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general answer.

If you plan to use composer on that live server then yes you need these files.

If you just upload your project files to your live server and you don't plan to use composer directly on your live server, then you can delete these files safely. Your project will run without composer.